# Можно ли хранить хеш-таблицу в файле? C++

Tags: c++, хеширование, unordered-map

Ситуация такая, мне нужно хранить хеш-таблицу в файле. Изначально я предполагал хранить ее в .txt формате, затем считывать в unordered_map. Но возникла такая проблема. Например, при удалении элемента из unordered_map сложность константная, но как удалить элемент из .txt файла с такой же сложностью, непонятно. Полностью перезаписывать .txt файл на основе новой unordered_map нельзя(по ТЗ).
Поэтому вопрос, есть ли способ хранить хеш-таблицу в файле, чтобы удаление элемента из этого файла тоже было константным?

Comment: Что мешает хранить в двоичном виде, используя в качестве указателей смещения от начала файла? Естественно, вместо std:: пртдется написать свою реализацию

Comment: Я думаю, никаких проблем хранить её в файле, все время добавляя элементы в конц файла. То есть, ничего из файла не удаляется, файл всё время растёт, а при считывании в map последовательно заносятся все считанные из файла значения - кто последний, тот и молодец. Решение простое, но дико расточительное! А что поделаешь - файлы!

Comment: не храни мап в файле. храни в каталоге )))) каждый элемент в отдельном файле. с названием ключа мапа. содержимое в нем. при удалении ключа удаляй файл из каталога. при загрузке читай все файлы из каталога. ключи=имена файлов, значения в самих файлах. ну возможно для ключей надо будет делать эскейп если код для винды и в имени ключа может быть неразрешенный символ.

Comment: ну и забыл еще при добавлении просто создавай в каталоге новый файл.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите здесь, как реализовать https://www.academia.edu/2799960/Maintaining_external_memory_efficient_hash_tables